# Window.close isn't working in chrome, neither are the hacky work-arounds

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, window

I am attempting to use a button to close a window in Javascript. Before the user encounters this button they go through three different aspx pages. Every one of these pages is opened using window.open() that I factored out to one Javascript file. However, when I attempt to use my close function (defined in that same javascript file) the console gives me the message "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.". I have tried using the hacky work around:

```
window.open('','_self','');
window.close();
```

but that doesn't work. I'm fairly sure Google patched that. Along with that I have tried `window.opener.close()` to no avail either.
Here is my factored out code in the Javascript file:

```
    function openWindow(windowLocation) {
        window.open(windowLocation, '_self');
}

function closeWindow() {
    window.close();
}
```

These functions are the ONLY functions used to open new pages. Any help?

Edit: Every page also has the same document.domain property if thats any help.

Other things I have tried:

1. Using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("javascript:window.close();");`
2. Using `window.location = "javascript:window.close()";`

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for... If "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it" is exactly the problem trying to hack around than whatever solution you come up with not going to work reliably and will be eventually fixed. Posting with tags frequently visited by Google employers not going to help hack to stay unknown either :)

Comment: What I'm asking is how can I close this window? I'm a beginner programmer and my understanding is that since I factored out the code and am using window.open() to open all my pages they should be script closable. Is this not the case?

Comment: Most of those hacky solutions have already been patched. Last time I got window.close() to work was when I messed around with HTML5 history/state APIs but that looks fixed now too. The best solution, IMO, is to leave the option to the user and display a message like "You may close this window."

Comment: So you're saying there's no way I can close the window programatically?  Forgot to mention this in the question but I want to be able to close the tab on a button click. If there's no way I can do this I appreciate the input anyway!